# Working out linear word problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following word problem can you verify that my answer is correct?

Word problem

If marigold were three times as old as she was five years ago, she would be sixty less than six times her current age. How old is Marigold.

Answer

3x - 5 = -60 + 6x
-5+60 = 6x - 3x
55 = 3x

55/3 = x

x = 18.333

Comment: Let $x$ be her current age. Then $5$ years ago she was $x-5$. So if the condition held, her age would be $3(x-5)$. We are told this is $6x-60$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing some important parentheses at the very beginning. If $x$ is Marigold’s age now, her age $5$ years ago is $x-5$, and three times that is $3(x-5)=3x-15$, not $3x-5$. Then you got the next bit backwards: six times her present age is $6x$, so sixty less than that is $6x-60$. ($60-6x$ is *six times her present age less than sixty* or *sixty less six times her present age*.) The desired equation is therefore

$$3x-15=6x-60\;,$$

and I’ll leave the rest to you.